# Kaprekar numbers in Python

Tags: python

I aas solving a problem on HackerRank and the problem is as follows:

A modified **Kaprekar** number is a positive whole number n with d digits, such that when we split its square into two pieces - a right hand piece r with d digits and a left hand piece l that contains the remaining d or d−1 digits, the sum of the pieces is equal to the original number (i.e. l + r = n).

Alternatively, a modified Kaprekar number is a positive whole number n with 2d digits (if its number of digits is even) or 2d + 1 digits (if its number of digits is odd), such that when we split its square into two pieces, a right hand piece r containing d or d + 1 digits, and a left piece l containing the remaining d digits, the sum of the two pieces is equal to the original number.

We need to find Kaprekar numbers within a given range. So I wrote the following piece of code:

```
def checkIsKaprekar( num ):
    string_num = str(num**2)
    if num == int(string_num[:len(string_num)//2]) + int(string_num[len(string_num)//2:]):
        return True

kaprekars = [ str(i) for i in range(int(input()),int(input())) if checkIsKaprekar(i) == True ]
print (' '.join(kaprekars))
```

The problem with the above solution is when we pass single digit numbers, they are converted into a string of which the right half is the number itself and the left half is ''. Now I am converting these strings to **int**(), which throws an **exception**.

To avoid this situation, I changed my code to this:

```
def checkIsKaprekar( num ):
    string_num = str(num**2)
    left_string = string_num[:len(string_num)//2]
    right_string = string_num[len(string_num)//2:]
    left_num = int(left_string) if left_string != '' else 0
    right_num = int(right_string) if right_string != '' else 0
    if num == left_num + right_num:
        return True

kaprekars = [ str(i) for i in range(int(input()),int(input())) if checkIsKaprekar(i) == True ]
print (' '.join(kaprekars))
```

But I don't like this code even though it does solve the purpose. How can I tweak my original code to produce the right output?

Link to the question: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/kaprekar-numbers

**Is there any way I can specify a default value of 0 if the string is ''?**

Comment: You can just replace `int(string_num[:len(string_num)//2])` by `int('0'+string_num[:len(string_num)//2])`.

Comment: @B.M. Hahaha. Thanks a lot mate. Should have thought of this one myself

Answer (score 0):

As answered by B.M. int('0'+string_num[:len(string_num)//2]) works perfectly. int('0'+'') produces 0.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the cleanest way would be to define a function like this:

```python
def to_int(s)
    return int(s) if s else 0
```

But it may not be worth the overhead in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It's often convenient to solve  problems on integers ... with integers:

```
def kaprekar(n):
    l=1
    while l<=n : l*=10
    return n== (n*n)//l + (n*n)%l

[print(x,end=' ') for x in range(1,100) if kaprekar(x)]
# 1 9 45 55 99
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def checkIsKaprekar( num ):
        if(num==1):
            return True
        elif((num**2)<15):
            return False
        string_num = str(num**2)
        if num == int(string_num[:len(string_num)//2]) + int(string_num[len(string_num)//2:]):
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find Kaprekar numbers within a given range by testing each number for the given condition in the given range. For example,

```
def print_Kaprekar_nums(start, end):
    for i in range(start, end + 1):
        # Get the digits from the square in a list:
        sqr = i ** 2
        digits = str(sqr)

        # Now loop from 1 to length of the number - 1, sum both sides and check
        length = len(digits)
        for x in range(1, length):
            left = int("".join(digits[:x])) 
            right = int("".join(digits[x:]))
            if (left + right) == i:
                print("Number: " + str(i) + "Left: " + str(left) + " Right: " + str(right))

print_Kaprekar_nums(150, 8000)
```

This will give the output:

```
Number: 297Left: 88 Right: 209
Number: 703Left: 494 Right: 209
Number: 999Left: 998 Right: 1
Number: 1000Left: 1000 Right: 0
Number: 2223Left: 494 Right: 1729
Number: 2728Left: 744 Right: 1984
Number: 4879Left: 238 Right: 4641
Number: 4950Left: 2450 Right: 2500
Number: 5050Left: 2550 Right: 2500
Number: 5292Left: 28 Right: 5264
Number: 7272Left: 5288 Right: 1984
Number: 7777Left: 6048 Right: 1729
```